# Does a Spelleater Bloodrager with negative cha mod get slots to eat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

The [Spelleater](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/classOptions/bloodrager.html#Spelleater) Bloodrager gets the spell eat abilities that allows him to convert spell slots to self healing.

> Spell Eating (Su): At 5th level, a spelleater can consume spell slots for an extra dose of healing. As a swift action, the spelleater can expend one unused bloodrager spell slot to heal 1d8 points of damage for each level of the spell slot expended. This ability replaces improved uncanny dodge.

The spell slots section of the magic chapter in the core rulebook states:

> Spell Slots: The various character class tables show how many spells
>   of each level a character can cast per day. These openings for daily
>   spells are called spell slots. A spellcaster always has the option to
>   fill a higher-level spell slot with a lower-level spell. **A spellcaster
>   who lacks a high enough ability score to cast spells that would
>   otherwise be his due still gets the slots** but must fill them with
>   spells of lower levels.

Bolding mine

Does that mean that a dwarven spelleater bloodrager with a negative cha mod still gets all his spell slots to use with spell eating?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

He basically would have slots without the possibility to cast his spells, slots that still can be consumed for healing.

As a side note: a negative charisma doesn't make you unable to know spontaneously spells, just to cast them.